# Spring configuration issue with Template Design Pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I am facing configuration issue in spring with Template design pattern.

App.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "Spring-Module.xml" })
public class App {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userExecutor")
    private IExecutor userExecutor;

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(userExecutor.execute());
    }
}
```

Spring-Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans default-lazy-init="true"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ravi" />

</beans>
```

IExecutor.java

```
public interface IExecutor {
    public Object execute();
}
```

AbstractExecutor.java

```
public abstract class AbstractExecutor implements IExecutor {

    private IInputPropertyBean inputObject;

    private IOutputPropertyBean outputObject;

    public abstract IAttribute getInputValues(Object inputObject);

    public abstract IAttribute process(IAttribute inputPropertyBean);

    public abstract IOutputPropertyBean getOutputValues(IAttribute outputPropertyBean, IOutputPropertyBean outObject);

    public AbstractExecutor(IInputPropertyBean inputObject, IOutputPropertyBean outputObject) {
        this.inputObject = inputObject;
        this.outputObject = outputObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute() {
        IAttribute inputAttribute = getInputValues(inputObject);
        IAttribute outputAttribute = process(inputAttribute);
        outputObject = (IOutputPropertyBean) getOutputValues(outputAttribute, outputObject);
        return outputObject;
    }

}
```

AbstractUserExecutor.java

```
public abstract class AbstractUserExecutor extends AbstractExecutor {

    public AbstractUserExecutor(IInputPropertyBean inputObject, IOutputPropertyBean outputObject) {
        super(inputObject, outputObject);
    }

    @Override
    public IAttribute getInputValues(Object inputObject) {
        System.out.println("getInputValues");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public IOutputPropertyBean getOutputValues(IAttribute outputPropertyBean, IOutputPropertyBean outObject) {
        System.out.println("getOutputValues");
        return null;
    }

}
```

UserExecutor.java

```
@Repository("userExecutor")
public class UserExecutor extends AbstractUserExecutor {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userInput")
    private IInputPropertyBean inputObject;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userOutput")
    private IOutputPropertyBean outputObject;


    public UserExecutor(IInputPropertyBean inputObject, IOutputPropertyBean outputObject) {
        super(inputObject, outputObject);
    }

    @Override
    public IAttribute process(IAttribute inputPropertyBean) {
        System.out.println("process");  
        return null;
    }
}
```

IInputPropertyBean.java

```
public interface IInputPropertyBean {}
```

IOutputPropertyBean.java

```
public interface IOutputPropertyBean { }
```

UserInput.java

```
@Component("userInput")
public class UserInput implements IInputPropertyBean {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

UserOutput.java

```
@Component("userOutput")
public class UserOutput implements IOutputPropertyBean {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

IAttribute.java

```
public interface IAttribute { }
```

User .java

```
@Component
public class User implements IAttribute{
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Error exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code on my local environment. The issue I faced was that there were missing default constructor for `UserExecutor`, `AbstractUserExecutor` and `AbstractExecutor` classes. After adding those it worked.

So I think your problem is missing default constructor. Try to add them and let me know if it works.